# Access to a particular RDD partition from one other

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I want get elements from beside partitions on the current partition when i'm using `mapPartition` or another function.

More generally, i'm curious to know how to get access to a particular partition from a RDD.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),4)
```

I would like

```
val rdd_2 = rdd.something(2) = RDD[Array(4,5,6)]
```

Thank you to tell me if it's unclear.

Comment: can you explain with an example.

Answer (score 3):

> More generally, i'm curious to know how to get access to a particular partition from a RDD.

For debugging purposes you can use `TaskContext`

```
import org.apache.spark.TaskContext

rdd
   .mapPartitions(iter => Iterator((TaskContext.get.partitionId, iter.toList)))
   .filter{case (k, _) => k == 1}
   .values
```

Internally Spark is using [`runJob`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4ee8191e57cb823a23ceca17908af86e70354554/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L1802) to operate only on selected partitions.

> I want get elements from beside partitions on the current partition when I'm using mapPartition or another function.

There is probably some hacky way to achieve something like this but generally speaking it is not possible. Assumption that each partition can be processed independently is pretty much the core concept behind Spark computation model.

If you want to access some specific subset of your data at once you can use a custom partitioner.